# how to prevent uilabel text from shrinking?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uilabel, nstimer

i am showing digits on uilabel and using timer to update text something like counting down..
i am using this font to show time like lcd clock

[CountdownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:48.0]];

i am facing two problems in this.

1. using this font the **dots**(**:**) between the digits is smaller than the digits.
2. the digits shrinks while counting down suppose if there is 1 and after it comes 0 then digit become large.and label acts like it increasing the font of that specific digit.

i want following things on uilabel.

1. a glow effect around the digits.
2. prevent shrinking(note-i have disabled the Adjust To Fit property of label)

also i want to know if there is any other font available than this to show text like 
digital clock.
and finally a request from all of you.
is there a way to run countdown timer using images of digits.

here is an image what i want

[image: Label]

Comment: Did you find an answer to 2. of your list? The changing size of the label?

Comment: @ david -
Hello david. I haven't find a solutions but i got the actual problem is with the font. So i decided to go with the images.